# Can I make a pixel based webpage responsive?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, pixel

first of all I would like to state that I am completly new to the world of web design and I am building my basics right now . So I have looked for methods of making a webpage repsonsive (make it zoom in and out without loosing content , and workig on different screen resolutions) and i have chosen the Restive.js method. I have stated the right (in my opinion) directories for the jQuery , the restive.js and my own CSS but when i zoom in on the page i have implemented the Restive it doesnt do anything. I am guessing the issue is that I have used mostly PIXELS to define sizes of objects and selectors. Is that the issue with the Restive not working or is there something else i am doing wrong ?

Here is the code for the statement of the external files and the code for the js itself:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="thezonesh.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js\restive\restive.min.js"></script>
```

and the JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').restive({
            breakpoints: ['240', '320', '480', '640', '960', '1024', '1280'],
            classes: ['css-240', 'css-320', 'css-480', 'css-640', 'css-960', 'css-1024', 'css-1280']
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Based off of the requirements, you can use the latest version of jQuery. Try running 1.11.2 and see what happens.

Comment: It looks like restive.js basically just adds classes to the body tag based on the device - so it has css-320 - if the device is 320 width etc.  So you'd adjust styles as it relates to those styles...so `.css-320 .yourselector {width: x%;}` - I don't think it just does all the css work for you?

Comment: yeah, from reading the restive.js docs it looks like it just adds classes to the body tag, you still have to add css to adjust your site based on those classes.

Comment: right so  I have to state for example .css-320 {
width: 320px;
} 

and so on for further styles ?